# Difference between "start" and "begin"

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, gerund-vs-infinitive

What's the difference between *start* and *begin*? Are the following examples equally grammatical? Do sentences 1 and 2 mean the same? Do they mean the same as sentences 3 and 4?

> 1. We started to know each other
> 2. We started knowing each other
> 3. We began to know each other
> 4. We began knowing each other

Comment: That sounds like two separate questions . . .

Comment: Rewrite your examples. You did not use the word "begin" in either of your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Start and begin are very similar, but you wouldn't *begin* an engine, you'd *start* it. You might *begin* a journey, but you'd have to *start out* on one.

> We started to know each other

and

> We started knowing each other

are both somewhat awkward. Personally, I would say we were *just getting to know* each other to mean that we had met recently and were talking about our lives, hobbies, etc. and say we *met* each other if I was talking about a longer period of time.

> I was just getting to know her when the party ended.

but

> We met in college.